# Laravel 6 no muestra las imágenes en producción

Tags: imagen, laravel-6, storage

Mi aplicación web funciona correctamente en local, aunque está dockerizada. Cuando he subido el proyecto a un servidor **Debian 10** con **Apache2** y con dominios bajo **ISPConfig 3**, resulta que no muestra las imágenes, a pesar de que he realizado el enlace simbólico `php artisan storage:link` y lo he comprobado, incluso lo he creado a "mano" con `ln -s` pero extrañamente no funciona.

He probado a darle todo tipo de permisos a directorios y ficheros, desde 755, 775 e incluso 777 para directorios y archivos.

Lo extraño es que si borro desde la aplicación, elimina la imagen, y suben perfectamente al directorio: `storage/app/public/upload/images`

Además, crea directorios para imágenes en miniatura y medianas mediante imageMagick y todo funciona bien, después de haber establecido los permisos correspondientes.

La url figura así: `https://midominio.tld/storage/upload/images/medium/CGAAR3TuOuVycbdkowv89f5Ktot3basAE0lrB31p.jpeg`

Ya no se que más hacer, mirar o rezar, pues llevo todo el día con esto.

El sistema es:

1. Framework Laravel 6.18.11
2. S.O Debian 10
3. Apache 2
4. ISPConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por fin lo he conseguido. El problema radica en que ISPConfig crea usuario y grupo, este necesita tomar control de todos los archivos. Al subirlos, el `owner` es el usuario del ftp, pero si además lo descomprimimos o hacemos un `git clone` resultará que el dueño, como el grupo es diferente del propietario del directorio "web".

Resumiendo, el usuario de ISPConfig debe tomar posesión de los archivos, pero además, se debe tener en cuenta que "posea" el enlace simbólico hacia `/storage/app/public`.

```
sudo chown -R userISPConfig:grupoISPConfig directorio
```

Y con esto tendremos nuestras preciosas imágenes luciendo en todo su esplendor :)

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada